# Need to understand the statement "Accessability is checked statically and not dynamically in C++"

Tags: c++, inheritance, access-specifier

I am confused regarding checking of access specifiers statically or dynamically. 
It is said that access specifiers are not checked dynamically. What does that mean ?

This example has been taken from different [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16668720/overriding-with-difference-access-specification-c) on SO. Consider this example

Example A:

```
class Base 
{
public:
    virtual void Message() = 0;
};

class Intermediate : public Base 
{
   //Is Message method virtual here too ? is it private or public ?
};

class Final : public Intermediate {
    void Message() {
        cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    }
};

 Final final;
```

Now suppose I do something like this

```
Final* finalPtr = &final;
finalPtr->Message();
```

The above wont work and my understanding is that in Final class the Message Method is private. Is that correct ? If so why does this work ? the method in

```
  Intermediate* finalPtr = &final; // or Base* finalPtr = &final;
  finalPtr->Message();
```

Is the reason why the above code is working because the base class pointer is instantiated with a derived class. If so why does the call to Message() work. The post on SO states that since the inheritance is public hence it will be inherited as public function ? on the other hand the function itself in the class has the private access specifier (since by default its private in a class). **I am confused here and I would appreciate if someone could clarify this. Would it be correct to say that if a base class is instantiated with a derived class. Then the access specifier of the base class method takes precedence over the access specifier of the derived class ?**

**Update :**

Also I noticed that if I change the `Intermediate` and `Final` code to the following

```
class Intermediate : public Base 
{
public: //Incase this public was absent then the following example wont work
    void Message() {
        cout << "Hello World! Intermediate" << endl;
    }
};

class Final : public Intermediate {
    void Message() {
        cout << "Hello World! final" << endl;
    }
};
```

and use it as such

```
 Intermediate* i = new Final();
    i->Message();
```

Then inorder to get the output `"Hello World! final"` it is necessary to mark the interface method as public. Why is that ? The method `Message` was inherited as public . Why do i need to mark it as public now ?

Comment: You should have linked the other posts.  Because you didn't, you will get the exact same explanation you don't understand.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The statement in your quote means that the access check is based on the static type of the expression you have applied the `.` operator to (or `->` which is equivalent to `*` with `.`).

If `T` is a type then for:

```
 T *t = something....;
 t->foo();
```

the the access check is for the name `T::foo`, even if the pointer actually points to an object of a class derived from `foo`.

Another way of saying this is that the access check must be able to be performed at compile-time. There is no such thing as a "run-time accessability failure".

---

In your code example you have:

```
Intermediate* finalPtr = something.....;
finalPtr->Message();
```

The name being looked up is `Intermediate::Message`.  The class `Intermediate` has `Message` as a `public` function, so this check succeeds.

Your comment suggests maybe you are unsure about the accessability of inherited functions. There are three types of derivation (somewhat confusingly, they are also called `private`, `protected`, `public`). `public` inheritance is the most common; it means that `public` members of the base class are also `public` members of the derived class.

Since `Base::Message` is public, and `Intermediate` is publicly derived from `Base`, then `Intermediate::Message` is also public.

To be clear, it is *names* which have access rights. `Base::Message` and `Intermediate::Message` are two different names, but they both name the same function.

In `Final`, it declares the name `Message` in its `private` section, this means that `Final::Message` is private. Even though the inheritance was public, the new declaration of a name `Final::Message` shadows the one inherited from the Base.

---

To answer the "update". When the code is:

```
class Intermediate : public Base 
{
public: //Incase this public was absent then the following example wont work
    void Message() {
        cout << "Hello World! Intermediate" << endl;
    }
};
```

you have declared `Intermediate::Message` as public. Therefore you can call the function through a pointer of type `Intermediate *`. That's what "public" means.  If you make it `private` then you cannot call it.

I don't know quite what you mean by "The method Message was inherited as public . Why do i need to mark it as public now".  When you wrote `void Message ()` inside `class Intermediate` it declares a new function. That function's name shadows the inherited name.

Comment: Then Would it be correct to say that if a base class is instantiated with a derived class. Then the access specifier of the base class method takes precedence over the access specifier of the derived class ?

Comment: There is no such thing as "base class is instantiated with a derived class", so that would not be correct.

Comment: I don't know quite what you mean by "The method Message was inherited as public . Why do i need to mark it as public now". This means that incase i did not specify the `public:` access specifier the updated example would not have worked and I would have gotten a "cannot access method Message"

Comment: @Rajeshwar In a `class` the default access is `private:` (i.e. the accessability of names you declare before you wrote `public:`, `protected:`, or `private:`)

Comment: I understand that. After going through your answer its starting to make sense. I am still in the process of absorbing this information

Comment: @Rajeshwar it sounds like you are unsure about how access works, maybe do some examples that don't involve pointers or references (just `Base b; Intermediate i; Final f;`) until you are sure you understand that

Answer (score 4):

This checking is done at compile time only.

You have made Message () public in final so it can be called from final.

The Intermediate class has no knowledge of how Message is defined in the Final class.

Comment: Then will this be correct ?   if a base class is instantiated with a derived class. Then the access specifier of the base class method takes precedence over the access specifier of the derived class ?

Comment: @Rajeshwar If you have a pointer to the base class, you can only use the base class interface, the compiler has no knowledge of what that pointer actually points to.

Comment: What? He made Message() private in class Final, so it can not be called via a reference/pointer to Final. This is checked (statically) at compile time though, so even if at runtime the (dynamic) type of the object is Final, the function remains accessible.

Answer (score 1):

To make Matt McNabb's answer shorter.
if you don't specify the function's access it's private. Like Final::Message

it is possible for a derived class to lower the accessibility of the parent class. This is useful in some cases (like blocking default/copy constructors, etc)